# UIlabel trailing space not working

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a label in a tableview cell with several constraints in Interface builder.
The cell is self sizing and thats working fine.
My problem is, that the "trailing space" constraint is not working.
The text is not broken and goes to far to the right  - out of the screen.
I dont understand this. If someone could help me out, what be fantastic, because I am now searching for hours and dont find the root cause.

The Label is set to 0 lines by:

```
cell.commentLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

http://picpaste.com/p1-AmKNGkwx.jpg

http://picpaste.com/p2-7ODUyyoc.jpg

Comment: Remove the trailing constants n again assign the trailing constant but uncheck "add constants to margin". Please try this and respond

Comment: Can you please share the constraints of the tableview? It seems like the tableview is not constrained by width...

Comment: Unfortuantley this is not working

Comment: Alladinian: Here are the constraints of the tableView that is inside a ViewController

Comment: http://picpaste.com/p3-Mw8ZqlaK.jpg

Comment: add trailing constraint same as  title label shows just  before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting a fixed size (600 x 444 - based on your comments above) on your tableview, which is larger than the logical resolution of the width for most devices and this causes the cells to expand beyond the visible area.

So, you must remove the fixed constraints and add some relative ones (for example match the width of the superview & set the bottom of the tableview to the top of your 'footer' - or whatever makes sense in your case... you can even stick with the hardcoded 444 for its height - the width is the important one here)

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day. I changed the width now to relative to superview and its working perfect!

Comment: @fipsikato You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you like. Glad that helped you 